# download xml file to use for strings

Tags: android, xml, localization, contentful

I'm working on an Android app where i want to store my strings.xml file on a server so the strings can be updated without rebuilding the application. I want to download an xml file with the same structure and keys as the one i keep locally, but the text in the fields might change so when my application starts i download this file and use this file's values for all the strings in the app instead. Is this even possible to do, or will i have to manually change the values in every single onCreate field?

To sum it up; is it possible to download an .xml file when the app starts and select that file for localization of strings? The main thing being to select that file to be used for localization so i won't have to write my own system for handling it.

I have tried searching to see if this is possible, but nothing has come up so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Downloading any type of file is of course possible. I dont understand that you make a problem out of that.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve your requirement with Android resources. You can build similar module, keep the initial string set in assets and for later usage you could download from server.

Comment: @greenapps the problem isn't downloading the file, that part is easy. The question is if i can somehow automatically make the app use that downloaded file for localization or if i really have to manually replace all the strings at runtime with the ones i got from the file

Comment: Well than ask for that only. Edit your post and make a new subject.

Comment: Of course you can use an xml file to put your strings but not with using something like R.string.xxxxxxx as it is no resource then.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change resources like `strings.xml dynamically since it's a compiled resource. You can use another mechanisms for saving data in Android and get your strings from it, here's an official docs: [Data Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

You cann't modify any resource files at runtime.
  However, you cannot use the Android resource system to pull in those strings. You would need to write your own Java code that uses those values, including determining which translation to use for a given device (taking into account the multiple-locale support offered in Android 7.0).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

But you'll have to override the original ContextWrapper and replace it with your BaseActivity, override the getString method and try to map your downloaded xml file to read the String value.